# Complex numbers properties

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $z \overline z$ is $|z|^2$, but what about $z^5{\overline {z}}^5$ and $z^{25}{\overline {z}}^{25}$ or $z^{100}{\overline {z}}^{50}$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the rules (valid in any commutative ring) that
$$a^nb^n=(ab)^n,\qquad (c^n)^m=c^{nm}$$
where $n,m$ are non-negative integers.

Answer (score 4):

Generalize
$$z^n \overline{z}^n= \left(z\overline{z}\right)^n=\left(|z|^2\right)^n=|z|^{2n}$$

Comment: Nicely answered.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: complex multiplication is commutative. Thus, for example, $z^{5}\bar{z}^{5} = (z\bar{z})(z\bar{z})\cdots(z\bar{z}) = (z\bar{z})^{5} = (|z|^{2})^{5}$. Can you generalize the rest?

Answer (score 2):

multiplication of complex numbers is commutative, also $\overline{z}^n = \overline{(z^n)}$ hence these all are what you'd expect them to be